# Eloquent - join clause with string value rather than column heading

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a question regarding join clauses in Eloquent, and whether you can join on a string value rather than a table column.

I have the code below querying a nested set joining parent/child records in a table 'destinations' via a table 'taxonomy'.

The second `$join` statement in the closure is the one causing an issue; Eloquent assumes this is a column, when I would actually just like to join on `t1.parent_type = 'Destination'` - ie, `t1.parent_type` should = a string value, `Destination`.

```
$result = DB::connection()
    ->table('destinations AS d1')
    ->select(array('d1.title AS level1', 'd2.title AS level2'))
    ->leftJoin('taxonomy AS t1', function($join) {
        $join->on('t1.parent_id', '=', 'd1.id');
        $join->on('t1.parent_type', '=', 'Destination');
    })
    ->leftJoin('destinations AS d2', 'd2.id', '=', 't1.child_id')
    ->where('d1.slug', '=', $slug)
    ->get();
```

Is it possible to force Eloquent to do this? I've tried replacing `'Destination'` with `DB::raw('Destination')` but this does not work either.

Thanking you kindly.

Comment: To answer my own question, the solution is to use `DB::raw("'Destination'")` - I was missed the single quotes before!

Comment: Answer your own question then ;-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Another best way to achieve same is :

```
$result = DB::connection()
    ->table('destinations AS d1')
    ->select(array('d1.title AS level1', 'd2.title AS level2'))
    ->leftJoin('taxonomy AS t1', function($join) {
        $join->on('t1.parent_id', '=', 'd1.id');
        $join->where('t1.parent_type', '=', 'Destination');
    })
    ->leftJoin('destinations AS d2', 'd2.id', '=', 't1.child_id')
    ->where('d1.slug', '=', $slug)
    ->get();
```

Replace your `on` with `where`

Comment: Thank you for `Replace your 'on' with 'where'` !

Comment: Old question but it was unanswered, and I like this better than the `DB::raw()` method!

Comment: I tried using `DB::raw('Destination')` in my case but didn't work for me also. However,the accepted solution works just fine for me. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

try using `DB::raw("'Destination'")`

Comment: The author answered their own question days ago in comments - you're just reposting it!

Comment: @Synchro hmm.. I didn't seen it. I haven't checked the comments. He could have answered his own question instead of commenting it.

Comment: I would have answered my own question, but don't have enough points to do so ;)

Comment: there's no need, there is already a right answer, all that is needed is to accept it ;)